# how does gstreamer select the default framebuffer?

Tags: linux, gstreamer, imx6

I am using **gts-play-1.0** on **Linux-iMx6** using following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:/home/straw.mp4
```

the command selects `/dev/fb0` and plays without any issues. But I want it to use the /dev/fb3 instead.

So does Gstreamer have the scope to config the framebuffer?

Answer (score 0):

Check `gst-inspect-1.0 fbdevsink` for the element's options. I would pick `device`:

```
  device              : The framebuffer device eg: /dev/fb0
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: null
```

So with `gst-play-1.0` you probably need to do something like `gst-play-1.0 --videosink "fbdevsink device=/dev/fb3" video_file.mp4`.